# Compare between MYSQL cluster and MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have created a MYSQL cluster using network speed 100-megabit Ethernet

- 2 Data Node (3G RAM)
- 1 Management Node (3G RAM)
- 2 SQL Node (3G RAM)
- 2 HAProxy with heartbeat cluster to balance between SQL Nodes

and I have created a separated MYSQL server (3G RAM)

I want to compare between this two MYSQLs and prove that MYSQL cluster is the best

I searched on the Internet for a big database and found (4 million row) [link](https://launchpad.net/test-db/)
and exported on the two MySQLs

I was surprised when I started testing quires the MYSQL server speed than MYSQL cluster, is this normal?
and how to compare?

Comment: And if you want a fair comparison you need to at least give the single server 15 gigs of RAM...

Comment: So you are fixing up testing because you want to show that A is better then B? Do the tests objectively.

Comment: @Jakov Sosic no but we always saying cluster beater than one server

Comment: not the case here :) MySQL cluster is still not a mature technology. You should avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I had tested MySQL Cluster some time ago. 
MySQL Cluster is only faster if you straight work with indexes.
The data is distributed between the Nodes. Each Node has an a Hash of all Indexes.
So each Node knows which Nodes have which Data.
If you don't work straight with Indexes the Cluster Nodes must communicate many times to determine the Result of your Query.
My result of testing MySQL Cluster: If your Application (or Test Script) is not Designed for MySQL Cluster you often had a worse performance than a single powerful MySQL Server.